# Marquee style ProgressBar not supported in Win7?

Tags: c#, .net, progress-bar

According to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.marqueeanimationspeed.aspx, the Marquee style ProgressBar is not supported in Win7.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

No, it's incorrect. The Marquee style is completely supported on Windows 7, even the animation speed.

Comment: +1. It's a leftover from the [2.0 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.style%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).